# How to determine current(=pending) Uniswap V2 Pair's price?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, pancakeswap, decentralized-exchange

Are there any ways to get the current/latest price of an Uniswap Pair (V2)?

I've understood that getReserve and getAmountsOut calculates the the return values based on the latest mined block?

But for example if a high volume pair is traded, I'd asume reserves should change according to new pending transactions. Are there any ways to estimate / approximate price for the pending block?

Thanks

Comment: there is no such thing as pending block, there is a txpool which doesn't contain private transactions. So predicting prices is useless. The Router contract has the function `quote`, check it out

Comment: Hey, by pending I mean txpool. The quote function does amountA * reserveB / reserveA, which is still the already mined block. So basically the only method to determine what price I'm going to get is solely using slippage (amountsOutMin / amountsInMax)

Comment: check out 1 inch platform, it will give you the best price and you don't have to do anything